# EXT JS Session Timeout

Tags: javascript, extjs, session-timeout

EXT JS - I would like to know how to check the json response for a session time out like if a user is idle for say 20 minutes or so if his session is expired or not

Comment: ExtJS doesn't have a whole lot to do with session management. It is a client-side library for building the front end of an application. Session management takes place in the server side, and using ExtJS as the front-end doesn't make much of a difference there.

Comment: so you mean I raise an exception from the server side and handle it in EXT?

Comment: If you make an Ajax request with ExtJS and it fails because session has expired, then sure, it's good practice to catch that error within ExtJS and take the necessary actions (show a message, redirect to login page etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Yes, Iam trying to redirect the user to login page when his session times out. Do you think that will have to be coded in global.asax Session_End event..Is there a unique http code for session time out.

Comment: There is no http code directly associated with session timeout (it helps to remember that http is a stateless protocol -:)) If your session is authenticated, a request after session timeout will result in 403/Forbidden status

Comment: I've formulated my comments into a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way of handling session timeouts in ExtJS. ExtJS is a client-side library, used to create the user interface/front-end layer of an application, while session management takes place on the server side.

ExtJS Ajax requests implement a callback mechanism. It means that a certain Javascript function is assigned as the callback function, which is called when the Ajax request has finished (either successfully or unsuccessfully). Here's an example taken from [ExtJS API Documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Ajax) - see parameters success and failure that define the callback functions:

```
// Basic request
Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: 'foo.php',
   success: someFn,
   failure: otherFn,
   headers: {
       'my-header': 'foo'
   },
   params: { foo: 'bar' }
});
```

So, in the case of session timeout, you could (for example) construct a JSON response, which would contain some error code (defined by you), and an error message to be shown to the user. The callback function should then check if this error is returned from the server, and take necessary actions (show error message, redirect to login page, etc.) when that happens.

Note that in the above case, from ExtJS viewpoint, the Ajax request would actually be successful. When the HTTP request fails altogether (HTTP errors like 403 and such), the Ajax request is considered unsuccessful. This is important because it is usually possible to define different callback functions for successful and unsuccessful requests (as in the above sample code).

Answer (score 1):

You can mock the timeout session...

```
 var keepaliveHandler = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function(){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : '/keepalive',
        method : 'GET',
        success: function(response, options){
//dummy server call each 60 seconds
            keepaliveHandler.delay(60000);
        }
    });
});
var timeoutHandler = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function(){
//invalidate session
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : '/logout',
        method : 'GET',
        success: function(response, options){
            Ext.MessageBox.show({
                title: MessagesMap.getMessage('session.closed'),
                msg: MessagesMap.getMessage('session.closed.message'),
                buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                fn: function() {
                    window.location.pathname = '/';                 
                },
                icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING
            });
        }
    });
});
if(Ext.ux.SystemProperties.isLogged) {
    keepaliveHandler.delay(60000);
    timeoutHandler.delay(Ext.ux.SystemProperties.timeout);
//check for mouse movements
    document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
        timeoutHandler.delay(Ext.ux.SystemProperties.timeout);
    };  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was able to accomplish this in a different way - when a new session started and that the user's authentication cookie got expired, I am returning a response that includes an error message conveying session timeout.